# How to get the shine effect of UIButtonTypeInfoLight?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, effects

When tapping a UIButton of type UIButtonTypeInfoLight you get a nice shine effect around the button. Is it possible to add this effect to custom UIButtons?

Answer (score 4):

```
buttonName.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```